# "Не было счастья(,) да несчастье помогло"

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с запятой перед "да". В частности, поговорка "Не было счастья(,) да несчастье помогло". Нужна ли тут запятая?
Спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужна, поскольку в данном случае союз "да" употреблен в значении противительного союза «но» ([источник](http://punktuaciya.academic.ru/182/да)).

Comment: Обратим внимание на пропущенную частицу БЫ: "Не было бы счастья, да несчастье помогло".

Comment: Все-таки нужна? А то я смотрела, смотрела на поговорку, но не решилась поправить.))

Comment: А без частицы БЫ теряется смысл поговорки. Её другой возможный вариант: "Не было бы счастья, если бы несчастье не помогло".

Answer (score 1):

Здесь "да" употребляется в значении "но". Запятая нужна.